# Photoshop script to delete layer by name of multiple documents

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to write a script that will go through multiple open documents and delete a layer by a certain name. When I run it, however, I get the following error:

Error 8100: The requested action requires that the target document is the frontmost document.

This is my code:

```
if( app.documents.length > 0) {
    var LayerName = prompt("Which layer do you want to delete?","Layer name");
    RemoveLayers(LayerName); 
}

function RemoveLayers(LayerName){
    for(var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++){  
        var actDoc = app.documents[i]; 
        var Layers = actDoc.artLayers;
        var len = Layers.length;
        for (var j = 0 ; j < len ; j++) {
            if (Layers[i].name == LayerName) {
                Layers[i].remove();
                len--;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I would guess that "frontmost document" is the document "on top" - closest to the user.  There is probably a method you could use to "bring frontmost".  It would be a property of actDoc.

Comment: @theGleep Ah, thank you. I needed to make actDoc the active document!

Comment: You're welcome!  :)

Comment: @JerseyFonseca can you update your code with what you changed?